# Person with two user accounts answering their own question

Tags: discussion

I'm all for users answering their own question in a 'Q&A' style, but it annoys me when someone who is clearly the same person uses a different user account to answer or vote up his own questions. Here's [one example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189274/unable-to-parse-the-json-in-amp-script-in-guided-template-language).

As @data_kid pointed out in [another question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188869/unable-to-parse-json-using-guide-template-language/188967#188967), this person has two user accounts; he/she has a habit of asking a question as 'user786' and answering, commenting and voting up his/her own question as user 'SFDC' in an attempt to drive his/her reputation.

Is there a way we can prevent this?

Comment: There are several peeps out there doing this, and its kind of hard to spot them. Usually, the moderators intervene and get in touch with them. I have been reporting suspected dup. accounts here as well, all we can do is add info/proof here and wait for the mods to take action.

Comment: Who has the time for this stuff!!!! :)

Comment: It was a funny one. He forgot to switch accounts and starting responding to questions as "SFDC". Deleted it when I asked him why he had two accounts. Now I look like Im delirious and talking to myself